# Save ontology file OWL API

Tags: api, owl

I am saving an owl file as shown in OWL API example file.

```
File file = File.createTempFile("sample", "saving");            
OWLOntologyFormat format = manager.getOntologyFormat(ontology);     
OWLXMLOntologyFormat owlxmlFormat = new OWLXMLOntologyFormat();
if (format.isPrefixOWLOntologyFormat()) {
   owlxmlFormat.copyPrefixesFrom(format.asPrefixOWLOntologyFormat());
}
manager.saveOntology(ontology, owlxmlFormat, IRI.create(file.toURI()));
```

I also tried following code.

```
File file = new File("sample.owl");         
OWLOntologyFormat format = manager.getOntologyFormat(ontology);     
OWLXMLOntologyFormat owlxmlFormat = new OWLXMLOntologyFormat();
if (format.isPrefixOWLOntologyFormat()) {
   owlxmlFormat.copyPrefixesFrom(format.asPrefixOWLOntologyFormat());
}
manager.saveOntology(ontology, owlxmlFormat, IRI.create(file.toURI()));
```

Both methods failed to save the file. Please help.

Edit:

Following codes for creating the ontology and the manager

```
manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
reasonerFactory = (OWLReasonerFactory) PelletReasonerFactory.getInstance();
dataFactory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
pm = new DefaultPrefixManager(BASE_URL);
File file = new File(filename);
OWLOntology ontology = null;
try {
    ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
} catch (OWLOntologyCreationException e) {
    System.out.println("Fail to load file. " + e);
}
```

For your information, the following code able to save (modified) ontology to the original file.

```
manager.saveOntology(ontology);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you receiving an error? Or nothing is written to the disk?

Comment: No errors. No file is written/saved.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the code used to create the `manager` and `ontology` instances? I've tried the code described here and it works fine on my setting.

Comment: I have edited the question with code for creating the manager and the ontology. thank you.

Comment: which code did you test,
File file = File.createTempFile("sample", "saving");  or  File file = new File("sample.owl");

Comment: I tried both options, they both worked. See my answer, please comment in case you still face a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should read an existing ontology file (`test.owl`) and save it in a different format (`test-format.owl`). Make sure the original file exists and contains axioms (the `getAxiomCount()` method.

```java
//Create the manager
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
//File with an existing ontology - make sure it's there!
File file = new File("/home/test.owl");
//Load the ontology from the file
OWLOntology ontology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
//Check if the ontology contains any axioms     
System.out.println("Number of axioms: " + ontology.getAxiomCount());

//Create a file for the new format
File fileformated = new File("/home/test-format.owl");
//Save the ontology in a different format
OWLOntologyFormat format = manager.getOntologyFormat(ontology);
OWLXMLOntologyFormat owlxmlFormat = new OWLXMLOntologyFormat();
if (format.isPrefixOWLOntologyFormat()) { 
  owlxmlFormat.copyPrefixesFrom(format.asPrefixOWLOntologyFormat()); 
}
manager.saveOntology(ontology, owlxmlFormat, IRI.create(fileformated.toURI()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the file you're creating is a temp file - it is not supposed to exist after the code has exited.

I suppose you want a permanent record; in which case, create a file the regular way:

```
File file = new File("path/to/file");
```

Edit: I noticed you tried this too. Do you have write access to the folder the code is running in? Did you get any errors reported?

Comment: No errors and the code runs fine. I do have write access to the folder.

Comment: which operating system and which Java version are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows 7 and jdk7.